# Why do these two bubble sort implementations differ significantly in runtime if they have similar numbers of steps and swaps?

Tags: c

I was trying to implement bubble sort in C. [I've done so in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/jshin47/3dc010296e595dd2a31195ca4d53f3d0)

I implemented the algorithm laid out on Wikipedia's article for bubble sort, `sort_bubble`, and compared it to a reference implementation I found on github, `bubble_sort`:

```
typedef struct Bubble_Sort_Stats {
    int num_swaps;
    int num_steps;
} bubble_sort_stats_t;

bubble_sort_stats_t bubble_sort(int arr[], int n) {
    bubble_sort_stats_t stats;
    stats.num_swaps = 0;
    stats.num_steps = 0;

    int temp;
    int i;
    int j;

    while (i < n) {
        j = 0;
        while (j < i) {
            stats.num_steps++;
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                stats.num_swaps++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return stats;
}

bubble_sort_stats_t sort_bubble(int array[], int length_of_array) {
    bubble_sort_stats_t stats;
    stats.num_swaps = 0;
    stats.num_steps = 0;

    int n = length_of_array;
    int new_n;
    while (n >= 1) {
        new_n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            stats.num_steps++;

            if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
                int l = array[i];
                stats.num_swaps++;
                new_n = i + 1;
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = l;
            }
        }
        n = new_n;
    }

    return stats;
}

#define BIG 10000

int main() {
    int nums1[BIG], nums2[BIG];
    for (int i = 0; i < BIG; i++) {
        int newInt = rand() * BIG;;
        nums1[i] = newInt;
        nums2[i] = newInt;
    }

    long start, end;
    bubble_sort_stats_t stats;

    start = clock();
    stats = bubble_sort(nums2, BIG);
    end = clock();
    printf("It took %ld ticks and %d steps to do %d swaps\n\n", end - start, stats.num_steps, stats.num_swaps);

    start = clock();
    stats = sort_bubble(nums1, BIG);
    end = clock();
    printf("It took %ld ticks and %d steps to do %d swaps\n\n", end - start, stats.num_steps, stats.num_swaps);

    for (int i = 0; i < BIG; i++) {
        if (nums1[i] != nums2[i]) {
            printf("ERROR at position %d - nums1 value: %d, nums2 value: %d", i, nums1[i], nums2[i]);
        }

        if (i > 0) {
            if (nums1[i - 1] > nums1[i]) {
                printf("BAD SORT at position %d - nums1 value: %d", i, nums1[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I run this program I get these results:

```
It took 125846 ticks and 49995000 steps to do 25035650 swaps

It took 212430 ticks and 49966144 steps to do 25035650 swaps
```

That is, the number of swaps is identical, and `sort_bubble` actually takes *fewer* steps, but it takes almost twice as long for this size of array!

My suspicion is that the difference has something to do with the control structure itself, the indices, something like that. But I don't really know enough about how the c compiler works to guess further, and I don't know how I would go about even determining this by debugging.

So I would like to know why but also how I could figure this out empirically.

Comment: Do you see the same difference if in `bubble_sort()` you assign a value to variable `i` before using it?  That function exhibits undefined behavior as a result of using `i` when its value is indeterminate.  On a related note, have you verified that both sorts work correctly (or at least that both produce the same result)?

Comment: Maybe pipeline issue - notice the `i` and `j` in the first method are increased in a predicted way but the check of the while condition in the second method use `n` which is changed as last step of the loop. And also try to declare and init all of the var at the start of each method

Comment: There is no empirically reason one code _should_ have significant run time performance different than the other.  Simply your compiler was able to optimize one better than the other.  Although perhaps informative, these are both O(n * n) and would be bested with various O(n*ln(n)) approaches.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes, I added a for loop to compare `nums1` and `nums2`, and check that every element is less than or equal to the next

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: first of all, turn on all your warnings and set them to be reported as errors. Then, turn on compiler optimization and run without a debugger attached. Then you'll have a starting point for manual optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Your `bubble_sort` isn't actually a bubble sort: it doesn't only compare adjacent pairs.

It is an insertion sort with the inner loop oddly reversed, which still works as intended. It can be rewritten as follows, without changing the number of steps or swaps.

```
bubble_sort_stats_t bubble_sort(int arr[], int n) {
    bubble_sort_stats_t stats;
    stats.num_swaps = 0;
    stats.num_steps = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            stats.num_steps++;
            if (arr[j-1] > arr[j]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = temp;

                stats.num_swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
    return stats;
}
```

To get a proper insertion sort from this, simply move the `if` condition into the inner loop, as follows.

```
bubble_sort_stats_t bubble_sort(int arr[], int n) {
    bubble_sort_stats_t stats;
    stats.num_swaps = 0;
    stats.num_steps = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--) {
            stats.num_steps++;

            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = temp;

            stats.num_swaps++;
        }
    }
    return stats;
}
```

This way, you can see that the number of steps is actually equal to the number of swaps, and less than the number of steps of the actual bubble sort (`sort_bubble`).

Comment: This may explain the different in the steps but how does it answer the question about the time different?

Comment: @DavidWinder I'm not sure, so I won't speculate, but it could be the effect of branch prediction.